# Filter out entries in dictionary based on the sum of the keys

Tags: python, dictionary

```
# given I want to find the x largest,

dictionary = {'cat': (3,4,5), 'meow': (6,4,1), 'dog': (1,2,3)}
x = list(dictionary.values())
lst = []
for i in x:
    lst.append(sum(i))
for num in range (x-1):
    final = (filter(lambda x: sum(x.key()) == lst[num] , dictionary)
print(final)

# expected answer (if x = 1):
{"cat": (3,4,5)} 
#because it has the largest sum (3+4+5)
```

This is what I got so far, but I got EOL while scanning string literal error which means I can't even test to see if it's right.

EDIT: Just tried another method, which seems more succinct. However, how to make it loop for the entire dictionary?

```
def wrtd2(s):
    dictionary = {}
    for val in s:
        x = max(list(s.items()), key = lambda x: sum(x[1]))
        if x[0] not in dictionary:
            dictionary[x[0]] = x[1]
    return dictionary
```

Comment: You have uneven parentheses on line with `final =`... anyway you want `max(dictionary.items(), key = lambda x: sum(x[1]))`

Comment: in this case max will work because it so happens that my x is 1. What if I want to find more than 1?

Comment: Ah yes, in that case use the same key function but checkout `heapq.nlargest()` or just `sorted()` and then taking the first `x` items via slicing

Comment: Hey thanks alot. I actually checked out the link that you sent for the duplicate and I like a solution inside. But there's a problem. Using the max function, it only loops once and finds the max. But I want it to keep on looping until a sorted dictionary is returned. Mind sharing some ideas on how to do that? I'll post the code in the question.

Comment: `sorted(dictionary.items(), key = lambda x: sum(x[1]))`

Comment: Whew..finally got it in a proper dictionary after abit of trial and error. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Good, just remember dictionaries are not ordered (generally), so if you're passing the `sorted()` construct to `dict()` then you're doing it wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `max` with `map` to retrieve the maximum value sum.

Then filter your dictionary via a dictionary comprehension.

```
d = {'cat': (3,4,5), 'meow': (6,4,1), 'dog': (1,2,3)}

maxval = max(map(sum, d.values()))

res = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if sum(v) == maxval}

# {'cat': (3, 4, 5)}
```